# SQL for DB2 - Comparing a column with itself with values from different years

Tags: sql, for-loop, db2

I am trying to compare a column (which has numeric values) to itself but for a different year (from the same table)

My query reads something like this:

```
SELECT  
    CYData.Column1, CYData.Column2, CYData.Year,     
    PYData.Column1,PYData.Column2, PYData.Year
FROM
    DB1.Table1 CYData
INNER JOIN
    DB1.Table1 PYData ON CYData.Column1 = PYData.Column1
                      AND CYData.Year = 2013
                      AND PYData.Year = 2012;
```

Is this an efficient query? It seems to crash the server. What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine as long as an index exists on COLUMN1 and YEAR.

If that's the complete query and there's lots of other columns, then an index on (COLUMN1, YEAR, COLUMN2) would allow the DB to fill the request just from the index without have to read the table itself.

Comment: Thanks Charles. It is indexed on Column 1 and Column 2 but not year. The query is returning about 8 columns total. Perhaps need to break it down into 2 separate queries and then use a join...

Comment: You need an index on year.  That's the only thing that will help.  Without it, the system is probably building a temporary one.  Ideally (COLUMN1, YEAR)  but two separate indexes, one for COLUMN1 and one for YEAR may be good enough.